# jQuery.scrollSpeed script won't let me scroll at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, smooth-scrolling

I've been trying to  get a smooth scrolling system using [this jQuery script](https://github.com/nathco/jQuery.scrollSpeed)

Including version 1.0 only allows me to scroll up
Version 1.0.1 is the same
And version 1.0.2 prevents me from scrolling at all.

Can someone show me how to include it in a webpage? I've tried copying code from [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EddVqa) codepen but have had no success.

```
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Custom scrolling speed with jQuery
    // Source: github.com/ByNathan/jQuery.scrollSpeed
    // Version: 1.0

    (function($) {

      jQuery.scrollSpeed = function(step, speed) {

        var $document = $(document),

          $window = $(window),

          $body = $('html, body'),

          viewport = $window.height(),

          top = 0,

          scroll = false;

        if (window.navigator.msPointerEnabled)

          return false;

        $window.on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {

          scroll = true;

          if (e.originalEvent.wheelDeltaY < 0 || e.originalEvent.detail > 0)

            top = (top + viewport) >= $document.height() ? top : top += step;

          if (e.originalEvent.wheelDeltaY > 0 || e.originalEvent.detail < 0)

            top = top <= 0 ? 0 : top -= step;

          $body.stop().animate({

            scrollTop: top

          }, speed, 'default', function() {

            scroll = false;

          });

          return false;

        }).on('scroll', function() {

          if (!scroll) top = $window.scrollTop();

        }).on('resize', function() {

          viewport = $window.height();

        });
      };

      jQuery.easing.default = function(x, t, b, c, d) {

        return -c * ((t = t / d - 1) * t * t * t - 1) + b;
      };

    })(jQuery);
  </script>

  <script>
    jQuery.scrollSpeed(200, 800)
  </script>

  <style>
    h1 {
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      position: fixed;
      top: 50%;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      text-shadow: 3px 3px 8px black;
    }

    #section1,
    #section2,
    #section3,
    #section4 {
      min-height: 800px;
    }

    #section1 {
      background: royalblue;
    }

    #section2 {
      background: gold;
    }

    #section3 {
      background: purple;
    }

    #section4 {
      background: teal;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="">
  <h1>Smooth Mouse Scroll</h1>
  <div id="section1"></div>
  <div id="section2"></div>
  <div id="section3"></div>
  <div id="section4"></div>
```

[My current code](https://pastebin.com/raw/BWAkKw1Q)

Comment: You need to give us some more information. Like: a) what errors are you getting, b) share the code you already wrote

Comment: I'm getting no errors

Comment: I've also added my current code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding
`<!DOCTYPE html>` to top of `index.html`